# How do you keep rewriting the sheet for a new morph from breaking play rhythm?

Tags: character-sheets, eclipse-phase, pacing

In EP, it is as easy to change your Morph as it is to change your car today. It is much more frequent for Firewall agents who have to travel across many environments and face various threats.

I use the regular rules from the official books, and have encountered the following problem: it is time-consuming and rhythm-breaking to pause and fill out another character sheet with the new morph abilities. You have to work out all the stats, re-add the morph modifiers, take care of specific equipment, etc. Creating a new sheet for one character can take 10 to 15 minutes (or more if one needs to search info in rulebook), and has to be done with each new morph.

So there is a contradiction between, "a morph is equipment that could be changed easily" and "making new character sheets is game rhythm breaking".

I am GMing an Eclipse Phase campaign, and we are not able to solve this problem efficiently.

What we do to prevent this time cost:

1. My players and I have decided to reduce ego-casting. They often travel with spaceships.
2. Between game sessions, I spend lot of time to prepare new morphs (updating sheets) when predictable.
3. When possible, we try to not rewrite the sheet, and evaluate scores as needed/on the fly.

How can I prevent stopping the game and diving into calculators and rule books? How can I do fast sheets updates?

Comment: Part of the core pitch for [Eclipse Phase 2e](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/507486226/eclipse-phase-second-edition) is streamlined resleeving.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I've found is to create a [dual-morph sheet](http://unpossiblejourneys.com/wp-content/uploads/ep-character-sheet-dual-morph-1_4.pdf). It positions stats in a way that makes it easier to fill them in for one morph, then quickly adjust for a second morph. Note that this still doesn't help in the case of repeated transfers from morph to morph to morph.

Comment: Tank You. It is a rally good idea. My Players have already a collection of character sheets with various morph. It is working well when morphing is predictable